# Change current directory to the batch file directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a `bat` file on windows that execute a [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) operation. The issue with the batch file is that I need to cd to the batch file directory first before executing the job, or else the script won't work.

How to change to the current batch file directory?

I tried the following code in my `procdump.bat`:

```
cd "%~dp"
procdump -h devenv.exe mydump.txt
```

But it failed, the error message is:

> The following usage of the path
>   operator in batch-parameter
>   substitution is invalid: %~dp"
>
> For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR
>   /?

**Edit: [The answer provided](https://serverfault.com/questions/95686/change-current-directory-to-the-batch-file-directory/95700#95700) is working, but there is only one catch: if my current directory is different than the batch file directory, then I would get a "The system cannot find the path specified". Anyone has any ideas?**

Comment: Where do you get that "%~dp" from?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Ok, I think I found [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) what you mean with `%~dp`.

I think what you really want to do is this:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
```

<s>(!) But note that this will still not give you the right behaviour when you're trying to execute your batch while the current directory is on another drive as `cd` doesn't change the active drive.</s>

**Edit**: Apparently (thanks [@Yoopergeek](https://serverfault.com/questions/95686/change-current-directory-to-the-batch-file-directory/95700#95700)) you can add the `/D` parameter to the `cd` command to let it also change the active drive.

Comment: For more information on these batch parameters, see `help call` at a `cmd` prompt.

Comment: By the way, you can combine those parameters like this: `%~dp0`

Comment: Your answer is helpful; but if my current directory is at a different directory that the batch file, then the above command will fail; even `cd /D` or `cd "%~dp0" /D` can't help.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: That your current dir is at a different dir than the batch file was obvious. But why would that command fail? I've tested it here and it works.

Comment: I don't know, very weird.

Comment: I've found the solution by using `cd /D "%~dp0"`. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Another alternative to `cd /D` is `pushd`... you can then use `popd` to return to the previous directory / you can nest calls such as this if you want to work up or down the stack.

Comment: The quotes are unnecessary. CD doesn't treat spaces as delimiters. Straight from CD /?: "CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to
CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes."

Answer (score 11):

I'd leave a comment to fretje's answer, but evidently I can't???

---

Anyway, regarding the note:
*But note that this will still not give you the right behaviour when you're trying to execute your batch while the current directory is on another drive as cd doesn't change the active drive.*

---

Use the `/D` switch in your CD command, and CD will change the active drive.

Answer (score 8):

You can do `pushd "%~dp0"` to go to the directory of a batch file -- even if it's on another drive. Additionally, that allows you to `popd` to go back to where you came from.

Comment: In an old-style Windows command prompt?!

Comment: Yeah, in cmd.exe. pushd has been around for years.

Comment: Thanks for this one. My script lives on a shared drive, so pushd handled the UNC path where cd didn't.